# Django Admin CSRF Verification Failed when debug=False

Tags: python, django, ssl, heroku, csrf

I'm building a Django (1.9.6) app, hosted on Heroku with gunicorn with a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate. When I try to save a model in admin I'm greeted with a Forbidden 403 error, with the message "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. More information is available with DEBUG=True." If I set debug to True I no longer get the error.

My settings.py file has:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '.example.com']

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['localhost', '.example.com']
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 60
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
```

I've tried playing around with different settings including CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN and I've cleared my cache and cookies.

I recently migrated my database from SQLite to PostgreSQL so I thought it might be related to pk counters getting reset to 1; I tried deleting my models in the database to fix this but I still can't save models.

I'm also noticing that one of my Django {% include template.html %} tags isn't working, not sure if that's related.

Comment: Have you tried the `'*.example.com'` inside the `ALLOWED_HOSTS`?

Comment: Doing so gives a bad request (400) error when I try to visit the page.

Comment: try ['*'] in allowed_hosts

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for ALLOWED_HOSTS or CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS unfortunately.

Comment: try SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False for the localhost